# why is the zod error message undefined when using zod-i18n in server side code

Tags: internationalization, sveltekit, zod

i'm using the following schema

```js
const propertySchema = z.object({
    rent_type: z.enum(['rent', 'sell']),
    title: z.string().min(10),
    typ: z.enum(['house', 'flat', 'garage', 'office', 'hotel']),
    price: z.coerce.number().positive(),
    area: z.coerce.number().positive(),
    rooms: z.coerce.number().positive(),
    address: z.string().min(10),
    description: z.string().min(20),
    beds: z.coerce.number().positive(),
    bathrooms: z.coerce.number().positive(),
    garage: z.coerce.number(),
    constructionYear: z.coerce.number().int().positive().min(1900)
});
```

and parsing over: `const propertyData = propertySchema.safeParse(formData);`

in my

```
+page.server.ts
```

so far it works great but i wanted to add now translations for the error messages and there is a package called [zod-i18n](https://github.com/aiji42/zod-i18n)

i'm initiating the i18next as described in the docs in the `+layout.server.ts`

```js
import i18next from "i18next";
import { z } from "zod";
import { zodI18nMap } from "zod-i18n-map";
// Import your language translation files
import translation from "zod-i18n-map/locales/es/zod.json";

// lng and resources key depend on your locale.
i18next.init({
  lng: "es",
  resources: {
    es: { zod: translation },
  },
});
z.setErrorMap(zodI18nMap);
```

but when i try to parse the error message keeps undefined which looks like its not loading the translation

```js
const schema = z.string().email();
// Translated into Spanish (es)
schema.parse("foo"); // => error.message is undefined
```

it works when i do the initializing in the +layout.svelte in the `onMount()` lifecycle - but how could i get this work server side ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import i18next from "i18next";

import { z } from 'zod';
import { zodI18nMap } from "zod-i18n-map/dist/index.mjs"; // <-- use mjs version

import translation from "zod-i18n-map/locales/es/zod.json";

await i18next.init({
    lng: "es",
    ns: "zod",
    resources: {
        es: { zod: translation },
    },
});
z.setErrorMap(zodI18nMap);
```

I had the same bug and just found a solution.
I think the problem is that by default the import takes the zod-i18n-map/dist/index.js and not the index.mjs (at least in my case).

Because of this, the "global" i18n variable isn't the same in the two files. So when zod-i18n is mapping the error, i18next *required* in index.js try to translate a key, for wich he has no translation since it isn't the same as the i18next that is *imported* in +layout.server and initialized there.

My IDE (vscode) isn't happy then, saying that there is no module declared (ts error), you just need to add "declare module 'zod-i18n-map/dist/*'" inside the declare global of the app.d.ts file.

Bonus point, in the [documentation](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#init) it is said that i18n should not be initialised multiple times. So the init could be inserted into the hooks.server.js file, outside of the function to be executed once at the startup of the server (just did this so not fully tested).

Hope it helps someone